# dynamodb: how to increment a value in map

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am trying to use dynamodb to maintain a **map** of names with their values

```
eg. {"scores": {"player-a": 10}}
```

I also wish to use increment operator to perform atomic increments.
However, i could find very little documentation on how to use/update dynamodb maps. 
Here's the python code I have so far

```
 import boto3
 ddb = boto3.client('dynamodb')
 ddb.update_item(TableName='ledger', Key={'week': {'S': '06-12'}}, 
                 UpdateExpression='SET scores.player-a  = scores.player-a + :val', 
                 ExpressionAttributeValues={':val': {'N': '12'}})
```

Comment: what is the datatype of scores attribute (map, list or set) ?

Comment: scores = map of names with their values

Answer (score 9):

DynamoDB update item uses ExpressionAttributeNames to prevent special characters in an attribute name from being misinterpreted in an expression.

Your update item consists of "player-a" as a key name which has "-" (hyphen) in it.

```
ddb.update_item(
    TableName='ledger',
    Key={
        'week': {
            'S': '06-12'
        }
    }, 
    UpdateExpression='SET scores.#s = scores.#s + :val",  
    ExpressionAttributeNames={
        "#s": "player-a"
    },  
    ExpressionAttributeValues={
        ':val': {
            'N': '12'
        }
    }
)
```

Comment: Is it possible to alter such code to insert MAP if not exists inside item?

Comment: wouldn't it throw error if 'scores' key is not available? how do we handle that?