# AWS DynamoDB update integer counter with Python/Boto3/Lamba

Tags: python, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I have a DynamoDB table with a integer value, which needs to be incremented using Python/Boto3/AWS-Lambda environment.

```
userMetrics
{
  "userid": 1234567890,
  "likemetrics": 0,
  "lasttimestamp": 1604553995
}
```

I am trying to increment the likemetrics integer counter using atomic increment method [dynamodb: how to increment a value in map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38163082/dynamodb-how-to-increment-a-value-in-map), but fails during testing.

```
   responseupd = dydb_usertable.update_item(
        Key = {
            'userid': 1234567890
        },
        ExpressionAttributeValues: { ":inc": {N: "1"} },
        UpdateExpression: "ADD likemetrics :inc"
        })
```

The error thrown by console is

```
{
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': unindent does not match any outer indentation level (lambda_function.py, line 34)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 34\n           responseupd = dydb_usertable.update_item(\n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please carefuly look at the documentation [here](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/dynamodb.html#DynamoDB.Client.update_item):

You are using mixed, Javascript and Python syntax. It should be corrected as below:

```
dydb_usertable.update_item(
    Key = {
        'userid': {
            'N': 1234567890
        }
    },
    ExpressionAttributeValues = { ":inc": {"N": "1"} },
    UpdateExpression = "ADD likemetrics :inc"
})
```

Comment: I get failure response like

Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "name 'N' is not defined",
  "errorType": "NameError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\", line 40, in lambda_handler\n    ExpressionAttributeValues = { \":inc\": {N: \"1\"} },\n"
  ]
}

Comment: Updated my answer. Added string quotes around N.

Answer (score 0):

See updated syntax:

```
dydb_usertable.update_item(
        Key={
            'userid': 1234567890
        },
        UpdateExpression="ADD likemetrics :inc",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={
            ':inc': 1
        },
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
```